# Air flow meter (AFM) current load

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am trying to understand how this older (~late 80's) vehicle sensor works in more detail.

[image: AFM]

It consists of an air flow meter shown above. The copper arm rotates on a shaft connected to a flap, as the vehicle pulls in more air the arm rotates and moves along the voltage divider network.  All of the wires from this sensor go to the car's ECU.  What's interesting about this is the resistance across pins 7 and 26 isn't linear as you rotate but the voltage output is.

I was also interested in the current draw on the +5V source and output voltage wires.  I utilized a current measuring tool and took measurements on two cars:

[image]

What I thought was interesting here is I expected the output signal (pin 7) to have very little current on it as I assumed it was going straight to the ECU's ADC.  The other odd thing is the large measurement difference here, used the same gauge, cars have the same ECU and AFM part numbers.

I decided to dig in and see what I could find on the ECU, picture below is the car's wiring diagram (left side) vs the Motronic 1.3 schematic.  Note that I believe on the schematic they have the two names flipped. The reason I believe this to be correct is two fold.

1. The pin numbers are correct otherwise
2. I assume since the temperature sensor (pin 44) is an NTC thermistor it would have a voltage divider as you see on the pin 44.

[image]

I'm not seeing anything on here that sticks out on why I'm seeing so much current on this voltage output (pin 7.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Would the ecu be checking the current or, more likely, looking at the change in voltage?

Comment: It's looking for voltage

Comment: So, if you don't match the equivalent resistance as offered by the ecu, then the excessive current you are causing may well affect the voltages you are measuring... And that is why I asked you what the ecu was looking for...

Comment: Understood but I'm just curious what is causing the stock system to pull so much current

Comment: If you understood then you know what you should do...

Comment: This comment "then the excessive current you are causing may well affect the voltages you are measuring" doesn't make sense to me.  How am I causing excessive currents when all I am doing is measuring the stock sensor?

Comment: Glad to see BMW doesn't use pitot tubes. On the other hand, BMWs aren't supposed to fly. (Sorry, couldn't let that one go, will accept any downvote, delete, account suspension with grace, heh.)

Answer (score 1):

BMW used quite some revisions on their ECUs. You might have measured condition 1 with an older or newer ECU. As an example, BMW E30 325i is used with 2 ECU ending on 153 and 173. Maybe the circuit you found doesn't suit one car. Have you tried swapping the ECUs from each to another? Then you at least know if it is ECU related or AFM related.

I would be helpful to mention which car you work on and how high the voltages on the output pin were.

Comment: Tomba, I was recently able to take current measurements using an inline meter and got around 1ma which to me makes more sense than the inductive style that got me the much larger numbers before.  I need to do it on a couple of other cars to verify.

Comment: Both ecus were 173s and the output voltage is pretty consistent between .25v near idle and 4.6v wide open